# Use drawer navigation without having a Screen inside it

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

I have a following `stack navigator`

```js
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
  <Stack.Screen name="AboutUs" component={AboutUsScreen} />
  <Stack.Screen name="ContactUs" component={ContactUsScreen} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Blog" component={BlogScreen} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

I want to have `drawer` (with custom drawer content) without using `nesting drawer navigators`.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw your issue and I am trying to helping you. I have made a custom design for drawer components. -firstly you can create an extra file for drawer Design like `DrawerComponent.js` and import in your code where you are creating a drawer navigator

```
import DrawerComponent from "./DrawerComponent";
const Primary_Nav = createDrawerNavigator(
{
  screen1: {
  screen: screen1,
  navigationOptions: {
  drawerLabel: () => null
   }
 },
screen2: {
  screen: screen2,
  navigationOptions: {
    drawerLabel: "detail"
  }
},
 {
 initialRouteName: "screen1",
drawerPosition: "left",
drawerType: "slide",
 contentComponent: DrawerComponent //<<< i added this
}
);

const PrimaryNav = createAppContainer(Primary_Nav);
export default PrimaryNav;
```

now in the `DrawerComponent.js` you can make custom component contents what you want.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from "react- 
native";

export default class DrawerComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {

    };
  }

  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingVertical: 40,paddingHorizontal: 20 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ margin: 20 }}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("screen1")}
        >
          <Text>Home</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ margin: 20 }}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("screen2")}
        >
          <Text>Detail</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
  );
 }
}
```

I hope it will helpful for you. thank you and happy coding.